# http.Request r.FormValue returns nothing/map[]

Tags: forms, rest, go, middleware, gorilla

I have the following Go code:

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
  "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
  "log"
  "net/http"
  "io/ioutil"
)

type rLog struct {
  Method string
  URI string
  FormParam string
}

func commonMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    formBs, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatalf("Failed to decode postFormByteSlice: %v", err)
    }
    rl := rLog{Method: r.Method, URI: r.RequestURI, FormParam: string(formBs)}
    log.Printf("%+v", rl)
    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  })
}

func main() {
  port := ":3000"
  var router = mux.NewRouter()
  router.Use(commonMiddleware)
  router.HandleFunc("/m/{msg}", handleMessage).Methods("GET")
  router.HandleFunc("/n/", handleNumber).Methods("POST")

  headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"Authorization"})
  originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
  methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"})

  fmt.Printf("Server is running at http://localhost%s\n", port)
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(port, handlers.CORS(originsOk, headersOk, methodsOk)(router)))
}

func handleMessage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  vars := mux.Vars(r)
  message := vars["msg"]
  response := map[string]string{"message": message}
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
}

func handleNumber(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  log.Println(r.FormValue("name")) // this returns nothing
  response := map[string]string{"name": "1"} // dummy response
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
}
```

What I try to do here is very simple.

1. I want to log all POST form data (it's done inside the `commonMiddleware`)
2. Access the form data inside the `handleNumber` i.e. `name` (and many more later) and do some logic with it.

The problem that I have right now is, the `log.Println(r.FormValue("name"))` returns nothing and I really wonder why that happened.

[image]

I've tried adding `r.ParseForm()` before `log.Println(r.FormValue("name"))`. But it didn't work.

And, when I add `log.Println(r.Form)` line, it returns `map[]`.

What did I missed here?

Comment: Have you used a Go debugger to inspect the contents of `r` when control enters your `commonMiddleware` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You truing to read `r.Body` twice, first in `commonMiddleware` with  `ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)` and then in `handleNumber` with `r.ParseForm()`. You can't. It's `io.Reader`, you can't read it two times. You can instead, for example, `r.ParseForm()` in middlewear and then use parsed form data. In middlewear `r.PosrForm.Encode()` to log, and in handler `r.FormValue()` or `r.Form.Get()` to extract. I think something like this should do

```
func commonMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    err:=r.ParseForm() //parse in middleware, data will be contained in r.PostForm
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatalf("Failed to decode postFormByteSlice: %v", err)
    }
    rl := rLog{Method: r.Method, URI: r.RequestURI, FormParam: r.PostForm.Encode()} //url.Values.Encode() stringifys form data
    log.Printf("%+v", rl)
    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  })
}

func main() {
  port := ":3000"
  var router = mux.NewRouter()
  router.Use(commonMiddleware)
  router.HandleFunc("/m/{msg}", handleMessage).Methods("GET")
  router.HandleFunc("/n/", handleNumber).Methods("POST")
}

func handleNumber(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  log.Println(r.PostForm.Get("name")) // or just r.Form.Get("name") or r.FormValue("name")
  response := map[string]string{"name": "1"} // dummy response
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
}
```

Comment: I do really appreciate if you can show it to me in form of code.

Comment: `r.PostForm.Get()` and `r.Form.Get()` will not work in your example if you don't call `r.ParseMultipartForm()` or  `r.ParseForm()` before'em